# script scrolling down / up in a html page

Tags: php, javascript, html

Need a script for my html page that helps me do the following: When i click on a text_head1 a list of lines scroll down, when i click on other text_head2 the last list scroll up and the new list scroll down! 
[image]

Comment: have you tried 'Accordion Widget` in  `jQuery UI` http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ ?

Comment: Or accordion widget in [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is pure javascript/jQuery.

If you're using jQuery, you can catch the click on your "text_head" element.
Then you add it a class "active" for example and use a function to display the list under the element (like show() or slideDown()).
Then on your next click, you'll search for the class "active" on your "text_head" elements.
If there is one, you can hide the list (hide() or slideUp()), and display the list under the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is called "accordion". It exists in many UI packages, like jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an accordion effect. A simple google query like `Javascript accordion` will get you started